# Symfony login user improve controller quality

Tags: php, symfony, security, controller

Welcome,
I wrote login system, it works but i think it is so bad code quality. Too many if. I want separate this code, cut down if amount and create some 'error login message' code. I need some tip to rewrite this controller method. It made my code more testable and pretty.
Thanks for every answer

```
 /**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = new Session();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $userData = $request->request->all();
        $newUser = new User();

        $foundUser = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CmsUserBundle:User')->loadUsername($userData['username']);

        if ($foundUser != null) {
            $encodedPassword = md5($this->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($newUser, $foundUser->getSalt()));
            if ($encodedPassword == $foundUser->getPassword() && $foundUser->getIsActive() == true) {
                $role =  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CmsUserBundle:Role')->findBy(array('id' => $foundUser->getRoles()))[0];

                if($role->getIsActive() === TRUE) {
                    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($foundUser, $foundUser->getPassword(), 'default', array($role->getRole()) );
                    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
                    $session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Pomyślnie zalogowano');
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));
                }
                $session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Role access can recent disbaled');
            } else {
                $session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Invalid password or login');
            }
        } else {
            $session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Bad data');
        }
    }
    return $this->render('CmsUserBundle:Default:login.html.twig',
        array(
            'sessions' => $session->getFlashBag()->get('success'),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: If you are using Symfony standard edition, please configure a firewall that out-of-the-box will handle exactly what you've built here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: Thanks to answer, but where can I tell my Symfony, if username not exist in database, return error message?

Comment: Also If username exist but is_active=false in database?

Comment: Take a peek at the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Comment: Your `User` entity should implement the `AdvancedUserInterface` for features like expired, active, locked. For more details about a login provider: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#forbid-inactive-users-advanceduserinterface

Comment: Yea, I read this but I can't find where is it what I am looking for. Maybe some code example or github link?

Comment: @Rvanlaak Thanks so much, everything ok, now i can't check active user in controller but still i don't know where create error message and decade how run it? Thank.

Comment: Can you tell my 

`$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($foundUser, $foundUser->getPassword(), 'default', array($role->getRole()) );
                    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);`
this should be in controller or maybe in service?

Comment: The controller only will be used once there is an error. You can try to look for authentication errors in your session or request: 

`$request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)` 
or `$session->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)`

Comment: So in the controller I write `$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($foundUser, $foundUser->getPassword(), 'default', array($role->getRole()) ); $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);` , implement my `User`  entity `AdvancedUserInterface` (can also write loginChecker class) and next check if any error `$request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)` , I well understood?